How to provide a dependency from another module in Android Hilt
I have this situation with Dagger Hilt:
There are main_api and main_ui modules. Also cart_api and cart_ui. main_api contains IMain, and in main_ui has MainImpl (similarly in the cart module - ICart and CartImpl).
main_ui depends only on the cart_api module and in MainImpl I need to provide ICart, but I get an error:
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] ru.primerka.features.cart.api.ICart cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements FragmentGetContextFix.FragmentGetContextFixEntryPoint,

How do I provide such a dependency (ICart) in MainImpl? Maybe is it possible through the app module?
My classes:
ICart.kt
abstract class ICart: DefInterface

CartImpl.kt
@Singleton
class CartImpl @Inject constructor() : ICart() {}

IMain.kt
abstract class IMain: DefInterface

MainImpl.kt
@Singleton
class MainImpl@Inject constructor() : IMain() {}

MainModule.kt (the CartModule is similar)
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class MainModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(IMain::class)
    abstract fun main(main: MainImpl): DefInterface
}

